# Why is HAVING col > AVG(col) returning no rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

This is a view showing each robber, their number of years in prison, the number of robberies committed and their total earnings (21 rows).

[image: ActiveRobbers2 View]

I then am trying to create another view to further manipulate the data in the view above. I want my new view to show only the nicknames of robbers whose NoYears (served in prison) = 0 and whose NoRobberies is greater than the average number of robberies.

```
CREATE VIEW ActiveRobbers3
AS
SELECT Nickname
FROM ActiveRobbers2
WHERE NoYears = 0
GROUP BY Nickname, NoRobberies
HAVING NoRobberies > AVG(NoRobberies);
```

This however returns no rows when I attempt to `SELECT * FROM ActiveRobbers3`. Can anyone see my problem? Cheers

Comment: avg(NoRobberies) will always equal NoRobberies in this group by. also please remove some tags ( is this mysql or postgresql ? )

Comment: I have to include NoRobberies in my GROUP BY clause though don't I? Normally I would use WHERE but I can't use an aggregate function in a where clause.

Comment: when aggregating, non-aggregates must be in group by - yes. although you will need to do a few queries and join them together to deal with the fact that you want the avg over all robbers not the average over each robber ( wich is always equal to the robbers data as there seems to be one row per robber )

Comment: My first view (which I derived the second view from) - each record was a robbery commited (who by and how much they took). Here the number of robberies per person are obtainable by counting the number of rows they appear in. Would I use this view to find an average?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is vague. Average of `NoRobberies` across all data of the table or data pertaining specific "Nickname".

Case 1: Average of `NoRobberies` across all data

```
CREATE VIEW ActiveRobbers3
AS
SELECT Nickname
FROM ActiveRobbers2
WHERE NoYears = 0
AND NoRobberies > (select AVG(NoRobberies) from ActiveRobbers2);
```

Case 2: Average of `NoRobberies` for respective nickname "Nickname"

```
CREATE VIEW ActiveRobbers3
AS
SELECT Nickname,NoRobberies

FROM ActiveRobbers2
WHERE NoYears = 0
GROUP BY Nickname
Having NoRobberies > AVG(NoRobberies);
```

Note: case-2 will give data only if a nickname has atleast two rows with different NoRobberies. Sample code is for MySQL

Comment: Sorry I'm referring to case-1. Thanks for your double answer!

Comment: Which `NoRobberies` value will be selected in the second case? The second case would produce inconsistent results.

Comment: @zerkms : 2nd case will give resultset where `NoRobberies` is greater than `Avg of NoRobberies of respective person`.

For example, nickname Daniel has two rows in table with NoRobberies is 10 and 20. In this case, you will get one row with NoRobberies   as  20 because avg of Daniel's NoRobberies   is 15.

Comment: @seahawk `NoRobberies` column is not either in a `GROUP BY` clause and no aggregate functions applied to it. Which means the value returned will be some random from the whole group.

Comment: @zerkms :  there is `GROUP BY Nickname` in second case.

Comment: @seahawk `NoRobberies` is not in the `GROUP BY` clause. So a random value for `NoRobberies` will be returned.

Comment: @zerkms: `NoRobberies`  in GROUP BY clause will serve no purpose because once you put it in GROUP BY clause , you wont get AVG of `NoRobberies` corresponding to a person. Secondly, putting `NoRobberies`  in GROUP BY clause represents no physical entity.

Comment: @seahawk I'm sorry, it's an sql basics. Please try to run your query on a real postgresql server and see that it does not work.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/48990 here is a fiddle for you - now just try your query and see that it will throw `ERROR: column "activerobbers2.norobberies" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 80`

Comment: And now it's syntactically incorrect. Please check it runs in sqlfiddle **BEFORE** you make your next guess.

Comment: @zerkms : thanks buddy :) .  Please check by keeping condition in WHERE clause and let me know whether its working.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/48990 `ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE" Position: 73`  --- please bother checking your answers **BEFORE** you post.

Comment: Now `ERROR: column "activerobbers2.norobberies" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 17` --- please tell me, is it **SO HARD** for you to check **BEFORE** you post?

Comment: @zerkms :  thanks buddy. I have updated the code. There was syntactic error. Columnn must be specifed in SELECT list if your are using mathematical function on that column in WHERE clause.

Comment: And there is still an error `ERROR: column "activerobbers2.norobberies" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 17`. Please check your all further attempts at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/48990 **BEFORE YOU POST**. "Columnn must be specifed in SELECT list if your are using mathematical function on that column in WHERE clause" --- that's wrong as well.

Comment: @zerkms : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55a73/3    and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0413   its working fine. Correction "HAVING clause".

Comment: @seahawk oh gosh, it's not postgresql there. If you pick postgresql on the top left you will eventually see the query is wrong (after half an hour of me talking it to you, not a bad result you think?)

Comment: @zerkms : its indeed a nice learning. I got to know that I missed obvious thing. Henceforth, i will mention SQL and its version as well. Finally I found the error you pointed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this works:

```
CREATE VIEW ActiveRobbers3
AS
SELECT Nickname
FROM ActiveRobbers2, 
(SELECT AVG(AVG_NoRobberies) as AVG_NoRobberies FROM ActiveRobbers2) as b
WHERE NoYears = 0
AND NoRobberies > b.AVG_NoRobberies
```

Comment: `ERROR: column "avg_norobberies" does not exist Position: 51`